# Python script bypasses PostgreSQL login?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm trying to work with a PostgreSQL database I have locally, and for some odd reason the program is able to login and make changes to the database without any username or password. I have done this same process in JavaScript and it required the username and password.

Either way, isn't it extremely strange that this simple python script can use the database without any credentials? Code below.

```
import psycopg2

user = "";
pw = "";

conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='log_to_db' user='" + user + "' 
host='localhost' password='" + pw + "'")

cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * from logs WHERE id=132")
print (cur.fetchall())
conn.close()
```

So, this script displays a row in the table. If anyone can help me understand why it's gaining access into the database without credentials (in addition to what I need to do to fix it), I would really appreciate it!

Comment: what does your pg_hba.conf file look like. that file controls authentication mechanisms, perhaps local connections don't need a login. also, execute the following query from your python script to figure out what postgresql user it is connecting as `select user;`

Comment: I am not sure where to find that file. When I did `select user` it showed me a user that requires a password. I do not understand how it works without a password.

Comment: on unix systems you can search for `pg_hba.conf` using the `find` utility. on mine, its inside the directory `/etc/postgresql/10/main`. On mac, if you install via brew, I think the file ends up in the child of `/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/`

Comment: Yes that directory exists, but I do not see it in there

Comment: For Homebrew-installed PostgreSQL, that file is in `/usr/local/var/postgres`. By default it defines "trust" for "local" (Unix socket) and "localhost" (127.0.0.1). Note that "localhost" is not in any way network accessible. Change the METHOD column to "md5" to enforce password auth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are couple possibilities:

1. Psycopg2 may login to your PostgreSQL via password stored in .pgpass
   config file
2. Trust Authentication: this is where your environment login may have been pre-authenticated.
3. Peer authentication:similar to trust authentication, but geared toward the database being hosted on your machine (i.e., localhost).

Given that your JavaScript code requires login cred to access the DB, #2 and #3 are most likely to be the case.

Comment: how do I verify this? how would I go about changing it?